# How to refactor an object with numeric values ​into a short size?

Tags: javascript

I need to display a specific number depending on the value of the slider. How can I  refactor such code if I plan to increase the maximum value of the slider to 100.  I think, writing an object such a long object is not the best solution.

```js
const p = document.getElementById("price");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

const rangeObj = {
    0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 4,
  11: 4,
  12: 4,
  13: 5,
  14: 6,
  15: 6,
  16: 7,
  17: 7,
  18: 8,
  19: 8,
  20: 9
}

p.addEventListener("input", function() {
            console.log(p.value);
      result.innerText = rangeObj[p.value];
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="price" type="range" value="" max="20"  />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a known patten from number to value? If there is not then only way is probably to list it out in some way.

Comment: @epascarello For example, after every 5 values ​​in the slider, increase the value of the number in the object.

Comment: Then just divide the slider value by 5 and round down.

Comment: Math.floor(p.value / 5)

Comment: @epascarello I tried to do it this way, but on mobile devices, when the slider moves quickly, the browser work badly. That's why I had the idea to transfer this code to an object. The object will be in memory and the engine will not need to make calculations every time when changing the slider.

Comment: unsure how that simple Math would be sluggish. My guess is there is something else you are not telling us about that causes it.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the range to step by 5? Could your whole problem be solve with `step="5"`

Comment: @epascarello it's possible, I just oversimplified my demonstration, but actually the cause could be something else. Thanks for the tips

Comment: You may need to use a throttle or debounce method to control updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this... I added a `toNearest` function that will round to the nearest specified value. In this case, I want all values to round to the nearest 5 (0-4 will produce a `0`, 5-9 a `5`, etc).

```js
function toNearest(value, goal) {
  return Math.floor(value / goal) * goal;
}
const p = document.getElementById("price");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const actual = document.getElementById("actual");

p.addEventListener("input", function() {
   const value = toNearest(p.valueAsNumber, 5);
   result.innerText = `Result: ${value}`;
   actual.innerText = `Actual: ${p.valueAsNumber}`;
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="price" type="range" value="" max="20"  />

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="actual"></div>
```